# How to pass an object from one case statement to another

Tags: java, arrays, object, switch-statement, instance

I'm trying to get the "player" object from case "A" to to case "G" but of course I can't do that because the object was created in case A and I have to keep it there. How can I move it down there while keeping the same instance? Beginner to java. I want to be able to edit a player in the array by pressing "G"

```
package hockeyplayer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HockeyMain {    
private static String choice;
private static HockeyPlayer[] players = new HockeyPlayer[12];
private static final String MENU = "Hockey Tracker\n"+
        "A-Add Player\n"+
        "G-Add game details\n"+
        "S-Show players\n"+
        "X-Quit\n";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

do{    
    System.out.println(MENU);
    choice = input.nextLine();

    switch(choice){
        case "A":
           HockeyPlayer player = new HockeyPlayer();    
           players[player.getPlayerNumber()-1] = player; 
            break;
        case "G":



            break;
        case "S":
            break;
        case "X":    
     }

}while(!choice.equals("X"));   
}      
}

package hockeyplayer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HockeyPlayer {
private String[] opponent = new String[10];
private int[] goalsScored = new int[10];
private int[] gameNumber = new int[10];
private String name;
private int playerNumber;    

public HockeyPlayer() {    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the name of the player?");
    name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the player's number?");
    playerNumber = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();    
}

public String[] getOpponent() {
    return opponent;
}

public void setOpponent(String[] opponent) {
    this.opponent = opponent;
}

public int[] getGoalsScored() {
    return goalsScored;
}

public void setGoalsScored(int[] goalsScored) {
    this.goalsScored = goalsScored;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getPlayerNumber() {
    return playerNumber;
}

public void setPlayerNumber(int playerNumber) {
    this.playerNumber = playerNumber;
}

public void addGameDetails(){        
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What game number was it?");
    gameNumber[0] = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Who were the opponents?");
    opponent[0] = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How many goals did the player score?");
    goalsScored[0] = input.nextInt();        
}    
}
```

Comment: I forgot my other page of code, but theres a addGameDetails() method and Hockey() constructor. I want to pass my instance/object to the addGameDetails() by pressing G.

Comment: can you also add that code as well, if the answer that I posted below doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare a `HockeyPlayer` instance outside of `switch statement` like this:

```
HockeyPlayer player = null;  
do{    
System.out.println(MENU);
choice = input.nextLine();    
switch(choice){
    case "A":
       player = new HockeyPlayer();        
       players[player.getPlayerNumber()-1] = player; 
        break;
    case "G":
       player.addGameDetails(); //invoke the method here for case G
        break;
    case "S":
        break;
    case "X":    
 }

}while(!choice.equals("X"));   
}
```

The idea is that `HockeyPlayer` object should be accessible to all the `switch statements` so you need to declare it somewhere where it is accessible.

Comment: So whenever I ask the user for a number to enter to add details about after I made a player in case "A", how would I go about doing that? I have a addGameDetails() method in another class that I want to pass the user choice to.

Comment: @Evan post your full code. Then I will be able to see

Comment: There you go. Hopefully you can see the other page now.

Comment: Whenever I press A and add a new player, it goes through the default constructor again of adding another player.

Comment: yes I see that problem as well. That's due to when you call a HockeyPlayer() constructor. Let me edit my answer above.

Comment: I have to get it to be able to work with the default constructor, but i'm just not sure that it's possible.

Comment: @Evan What do you mean? Are you saying that you should be able to add a new player using default constructor? Is that a requirement? If not, then I suggest it is best that you separate adding-a-new-player logic to a new method. Also when you make neccessary changes to your code as I suggested, did you run into any new problem?

Comment: It is a requirement yeah.

Answer (score 1):

move the declaration of the `player` variable outside of the `do-while`, still instantiating in the `case "A"`:

```
HockeyPlayer player = null;
do {    
  System.out.println(MENU);
  choice = input.nextLine();
  switch(choice){
    case "A":
       player = new HockeyPlayer();    
       players[player.getPlayerNumber()-1] = player; 
        break;
    case "G":
       // you can use player here (assuming 


        break;
    case "S":
        break;
    case "X":    
 }
} while(!choice.equals("X"));
```